# $.slideUp() not working on elements in a CSS "display:none" parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site I am designing that has some nested DIV elements that I use as containers to hold expandable buttons.

The user clicks on a button and it expands to expose some more content.

Everything works great until I have a DIV that is inside of a parent DIV with it's display property set to "none".

Is there any way to force the jQuery .slideUp() method to minimize the expandable buttons regardless of whether it is in a display:none parent or not?

OR, what property/properties do I need to set to make $.slideDown() work properly on an element that was setup up in a display:none parent DIV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of applying slideUp() to the expandable buttons, try setting their "display" value to "none".

This way, when you apply the .slideDown() method it will think that element has already been hidden using the .slideUp() method.

Comment: This worked great, and I only had to change the css on the element itself and not its parent. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If the parent has `display:none;` then you'll need to show it before trying to slideUp the child.  You can do this with the `show` function.

```
$(divToSlide).parent().show();
$(divToSlide).slideUp();
```

Per the comment, you could alternatively, you could just set the display property to 'block'

```
$(divToSlide).parent().css("display", "block");
$(divToSlide).slideUp();
```

Comment: Actually, an easier way is to simply change the element's css display property to "none". This avoids the system overhead of processing more elements that you have to.

Comment: @henkojinko - fair enough, but can you please elaborate?  I assumed show just set display and visibility.  Does it do more than just that?

Comment: They do. However, if you want a particular element to be triggered correctly using slideDown without having to use slideUp first, you simply need to make its display property "none". That way, you don't have to worry about which ancestor it is nested in is hidden, block, or none.

Comment: @henkojinko - I understand.  But, if an element is inside of a parent that has display:none, you would still have to explicitly show the parent—be it with `show()` or `.css('display', 'block')`, before sliding up the child, wouldn't you?

Comment: no you don't need to since you are not calling the actual slideUp() method on the element. Once slideUp() completes it the changes the visibility and display properties to hidden/none. So if you start off with display:none then use the slideDown() method it will actually think that since it has a display:none then it must already have been acted upon by slideUp(), so it slides down.

Comment: @henkojinko - well you certainly understood OP's problem better than I did, but I'm still having trouble getting slideDown to work when an element is in a parent that's display:none.  Here's the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/kBgPf/  The element I'm sliding down has display:none.  When the parent is also display:none, nothing works.  When I take display:none off the parent, it works great.  I really don't care about being right or any silliness like that, I just want to know if there's some neat trick I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and none of the mentioned solutions worked for me the way I expected, as sometimes I lost the slideUp/slideDown animation itself when applying the `show()` function. My final solution was using a callback function to apply the style directly:

```
$(divToSlide).slideUp(delay, function () {
    // When animation ends
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

This way I could get the same result without losing the animation.